# create wizard for new users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wizard

I have a ruby on rails application, can you indicate me some gems or ways to create a wizard for new users (or if a user didnt use some feature, some button will appear). My objective is when a user creates an account or if hes not using a feature, some help would appear telling him how to do stuff, for example, after registration, tell the user that he can create a new project, and show how to do it (with the user doing it at the same time), and after that show how to create users ... moving between pages and changing the database records. the user can also skip not mandatory steps. Is there any good gem for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the "wicked" gem to be useful: https://github.com/schneems/wicked.

If you're looking for a more custom approach, you can implement a basic state machine to represent the states of the wizard. Each form in the wizard would advance the state of that user so they could resume where they left off.

Comment: how can I use the existing code? I think wicked is for creating new wizard adapted forms

Comment: Not sure what the existing code is. No matter your approach you'll likely have to refactor and redesign parts of your app.

Comment: i think wicked is for multi-step forms, I need to navigate through the website, also explaining how to use the features